# Problems with wsdl in existdb (PHP API)

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, exist-db

i'm trying to type a simple access code to the eXist database, but the php goes crazy about the wsdl:

The php code would sound like this:
 $db = new eXist();

And in the eXist class, it's by default
$user="guest", $password="guest", $wsdl="http://localhost:8080/exist/services/Query?wsdl"

Well, the php doesn't get the wsdl right:
SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '[http]localhost:8080/exist/services/Query?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "[http]localhost:8080/exist/services/Query?wsdl" in D:\facultate\WorkspaceTw\test\include\eXist.php:66 Stack trace: #0 D:\facultate\WorkspaceTw\test\include\eXist.php(66): SoapClient->SoapClient('[http]localhos...') #1 D:\facultate\WorkspaceTw\test\index.php(6): eXist->__construct() #2 {main}

The API from the exist-db should have put the wsdls somewhere so this root could be found, but can't find any wsdl in the computer.

Please help, i'm new on using SOAP.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for answering so quick. No, it doesn't show nothing when i go to the URI, meanwhile found the wsdl in the computer, but still can't get it why it doesn't make the connection to it.

For more details i can say this: I'm working on a local apache server with PHP 5.4 and i want to atach a XML native database called eXist-db. To connect to the database, i got a php library that works on SOAP to connect to the installed pack of exist-db via this WSDL. It seems that the WSDL isn't recognized, and dunno why. Don't understand how can i force the link to be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pasting    `localhost:8080/exist/services/Query?wsdl`  in a browser window and see if whatever server you are running actually has wsdls that are accessible.

If it works it should return an XML document. Let us know what happens when you try that and we can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quick. No, it doesn't show nothing when i go to the URI, meanwhile found the wsdl in the computer, but still can't get it why it doesn't make the connection to it.

Comment: For more details i can say this:

I'm working on a local apache server with PHP 5.4 and i want to atach a XML native database called eXist-db. To connect to the database, i got a php library that works on SOAP to connect to the installed pack of exist-db via this WSDL.

It seems that the WSDL isn't recognized, and dunno why. Don't understand how can i force the link to be made.

Comment: One more thing. When i try the URI for the WSDL, it says that the connection to localhost:8080 is not possible, not that it doesn't exist.

Comment: check whether your port 8080 is in used by any another application

Comment: What kind of apache server are you running?